# Where is it on topic for Xcode related questions?

Tags: support

When searching for the "xcode" tag on Ask Different, the following banner appears:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xcode

```
WARNING: Almost all questions about development or app distribution are off topic here. See the FAQs for details.
 
Xcode is Apple's official software development environment for Mac OS X and iOS
```

- Where within the Stack Exchange network are questions about Xcode on topic?
- Where is the FAQ? (A search for the word "FAQ" on the page shows up just the banner above)

Comment: Thanks for the question here! Does my edit to the tag guidance help or confuse the issue further? https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/20759/revisions

Answer (score 1):

The [FAQ](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help) can be accessed via the "?" menu on top right. But I agree, the wording is a bit unfortunate, I've changed it now (thanks for pointing it out).

As for on/off-topic:

- questions which involve code (C, C++, Objective-C, Swift etc) are off-topic but can be asked on Stack Overflow
- questions about Xcode as an application are mostly on-topic.

Comment: Nice work with the edit. I may want to edit since one thing that can help everyone is if we direct the discussion towards "what is the problem the OP faces?" Using an application, scripting that application, understanding Apple's service to developers all are squarely on topic in my mind. People that write code using Xcode where the problem is fundamentally about the code - those belong elsewhere. (Stack Overflow / Programmers / Arduino / Open Source / AI / Computer Science / Code Review / DevOps / Computer Graphics for instance ...)